# Need to group pair of similar rows together

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where I need to group pairs of similar rows together such that they are grouped by `[date]` column and `SUM(amount)` is 0.

Here's a sample code.

```
declare @data table (
    id int identity(1, 1),
    [date] date,
    amount smallmoney,
    groupId int
)

insert into @data ([date], amount)
values
    ('11/1/2020', 57.3),
    ('2/1/2021', 10),
    ('2/1/2021', -10),
    ('2/1/2021', 21.4),
    ('2/1/2021', 10),
    ('2/1/2021', -10),
    ('2/1/2021', 10),
    ('2/1/2021', -10),
    ('2/1/2021', -10),
    ('2/1/2021', 10),
    ('5/1/2021', 1.4)
            
select *
from @data

select
    min(id) as id,
    [date],
    abs(amount) as amount,
    count(1) as [count]
from @data
group by [date], abs(amount)
having sum(amount) = 0
```

The grouping select at the bottom groups 8 rows into 1 row, but I need 4 groups or 8 rows. Here's what I need the output to be.

| id | date | amount | groupId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2/1/2021 | 10 | 2 |
| 3 | 2/1/2021 | -10 | 2 |
| 5 | 2/1/2021 | 10 | 5 |
| 6 | 2/1/2021 | -10 | 5 |
| 7 | 2/1/2021 | 10 | 7 |
| 8 | 2/1/2021 | -10 | 7 |
| 9 | 2/1/2021 | -10 | 9 |
| 10 | 2/1/2021 | 10 | 9 |

I can probably do this with a loop operation, but I prefer if this can be done in a SELECT statement. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to assign a row numbering partitioned by `[date], amount` and use that row numbering when pairing up the rows with negative and positive values.

This does assume you have no rows where `abs(amount) = amount` and where the `sum(amount)` of rows with the same row numbering would be zero (i.e. no rows where amount is zero)

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT id,
                date,
                amount,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [date], amount ORDER BY id) AS grp
         FROM   @data),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY [date], grp, abs(amount)) AS sum_amt,
                MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY [date], grp, abs(amount)) AS groupId
         FROM   T1)
SELECT id,
       date,
       amount,
       groupId
FROM   T2
WHERE  sum_amt = 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much